# Using subtype in place of base type in XML - something like inheritance in object-oriented programming language

Tags: xml

Look at fragment of my schema, please:

```
<xs:complexType name="P">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="WP">
 <xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="P">
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="l-l-l" type="xs:integer"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
 </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="p" type="P"/>
```

Now,
I would like to be able to do:

```
<p>
  <name>someName</name>
  <lll>213</lll>
</p>
```

However, I got error that `lll` is not exptected.  I know that changing `<xs:element name="p" type="P"/>` to `<xs:element name="p" type="WP"/>` can help me, but I would like to use it like objects in Java or other object-oriented programming language.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A type derived by extension in XSD isn't substitutable for the original type unless the instance explicitly contains the attribute `xsi:type="type-name"`.

Comment: Could you give example adjusted to my situation ?

Comment: Assuming that there is no namespace involved, you would write `<p xsi:type="WP">...</p>`

Comment: Is it possible to lock possibility of use `<p>` without `xsi:type` attribute ? I want to force creating always some subclass elements.

Comment: Yes, you can declare the base type with `abstract='true'`. But please don't ask supplementary questions in comments: it's a new question and belongs in a new thread.